# Export react-cosmos in a way to work on the same nextjs project

Tags: next.js

I am using react-cosmos with next.js to build the style guide for the project. It works fine but it required running cosmos on a separate server even when the project is built and exported.

Is there a way to export the cosmos files in a way to work on the same server?

I followed the instructions here and they work but they don't allow cosmos to run on the same server as the app itslef.

https://github.com/react-cosmos/react-cosmos/blob/main/docs/getting-started/next.md